# Dashboard development and various tools

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-painless

We are trying to develop some dashboards in Elastic that we already have in Splunk.  Can you fine folks consider the following questions?  Any help appreciated...

(1) If I write a query that date_histogram aggregates data (such as the count of docs/pings in time-increments), I see the aggregated count data in the query response, but how do I do further commands/operations on that aggregated data?

(2) If I develop a query in the Dev Tools Console, how do I save that query and then use the query results in a dashboard, such as plot the aggregate data in the previous question as a line chart?

Answer (score 0):

(1) It sounds like a pipeline aggregation ([see docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline.html)). If you have a precise operation in mind, please refine your question

(2) I'm not aware of any feature to provide an elasticsearch query to obtain a kibana visualization. Nevertheless, all visualizations are based on elasticsearch queries, so you'll surely be able to visualize what you got in the dev tools. The most interactive and flexible visualization tools in Kibana are `Lens` ([here is a nice tutorial](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/8.6/create-a-dashboard-of-panels-with-ecommerce-data.html), which also shows some advanced features) and `TSVB` (here is a nice, although a bit old, [webinar](https://play.vidyard.com/dGC6z7xf7d8EhUv1sED3EQ?disable_popouts=1&v=4.3.10&chapter=1&type=inline&referring_url=https://www.elastic.co/webinars/kibana-time-series-visual-builder-demystified&autoplay=0&hidden_controls=0&muted=0&loop=0&disable_analytics=0))